# JUnit in Spring web project

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am new to Junit. Recently, I need add some test function for a spring web project.
So I add a new project only for testing.

Firstly, I add a test case for testing ADServiceImpl, and following is my test code.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ADServiceImpl service = new ADServiceImpl();
    UserInfo info = service.getUserInfo("admin", "123456");
    assertEquals("Result", "00", info.getStatus().getCode());
}
```

After I run the test and got a error is that 'endpoint' is null. But 'endpoint' is setting by spring @Resource(name = "adEndpoint") from xml configuration. 

**How can I deal with this problem?? Or is there other recommend for spring web project testing? Thank you so much!**

```
@Service("ADService")
public class ADServiceImpl implements ADService {

private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ADServiceImpl.class);

@Resource(name = "adEndpoint")
private String endpoint;

public UserInfo getUserInfo(String acc, String pwd) throws JAXBException, RemoteException {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(endpoint)) {
        logger.error("***** AD Endpoint is blank, please check sysenv.ad.endpoint param ******");
    }

    ADSoapProxy proxy = new ADSoapProxy();
    proxy.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    logger.debug("***** AD endpoint:" + endpoint + "******");

    String xml = proxy.userInfo(acc, pwd);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserInfo.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    return (UserInfo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you include the class declaration that your JUnit tests are in? I'm guessing you're not specifying a test runner (usually something like `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. This is what tells Spring to inject the dependencies from your config. See [the Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-framework) for more information.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave yes, that's a point. I don't have @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) to inject beans. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating Unit Tests that requires Spring to be running you need to add the following to your unit test class. For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MySpringApp.class)
public MyTestClass{
    @Test
    ...
}
```

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html)